# Fetching models along with corresponding join-models attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the models:

```rb
class Exam < AR::Base
  has_many :questions_in_exams
  has_many :questions, :through => :questions_in_exams
end

class QuestionsInExam < AR::Base
  belongs_to :examination
  belongs_to :question
  # This model also has a "question_index" attribute
end

class Question < AR::Base
  has_many :questions_in_exams
  has_many :examinations, :through => :questions_in_exams
end
```

Given an instance of Exam, I want to fetch all of it's questions along with the extra
attributes from the join model (like "question_index"). How can I achieve this ?

If I do:

```rb
e = Examination.find(1)
questions = e.questions
```

Then elements in questions array won't have the "question_index" attribute

I guess I can write:

```rb
e = Examination.find(1)
questions = e.questions_in_exam(:include => "question")
```

But this seems not so elegant since most of the data I need is on the Question model,
but the returned array will consist of QuestionInExam instances.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: `include` will fetch `Question` models for every `QuestionInExam` so you then call `qe.question` to get question attributes. The difference only in lazy or greedy loading of data. In the case of including you got maximum of 2 queries to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the Question model, something like this

```
Question.select("questions.*, examination.id")
        .joins(:questions_in_exam => :examination)
        .where("examinations.id=?", 1) 

# Note that inside "select" you can specified all the attributes you want from any of the joined models.
```

Once you are happy with your query convert it to a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html)

and your final call might look something like this: Question.for_exam(1)